# PHP, C# or Java library to push messages in BB channel

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have some data in mysql database. I want to send these messages to a BB channel. I have created a BB channel and I want an API to share all the messages in this channel.

Is there any PHP, JSP or C# library to do this.

I am new to this field and I don't have much knowledge abut this.

Please help.

Thanks,
Pravin

Comment: What is a BB channel? Are you referring to a BBM Channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of September 30th this was on the road map for BBM Channels but [no specified timeline](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/BBM-Channels-API/td-p/2373595/page/2#). You might try posting on that thread to see if there is any more news, especially now that Channels is out of beta.